# Gitlab CI MR pipeline runs against the rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a job that runs when an MR is created from main branch to develop branch though it shouldn't according to the rules:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: never
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_PROTECTED == "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH !~ /^hotfix\/.*/
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      changes:
      - Admin.Service/**/*
```

here is my workflow:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /phase-.*/
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^bulk\/.*/
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME =~ /release-.*/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /bugfix.*/
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /release-.*/
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^hotfix\/.*/
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
```

In my understanding the first rule should disable the job and the following rules should be ignored accordingly. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong. How can I prevent the job from getting into the MR pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH == "main" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH == "develop"
      when: never
```

The variable names are incorrect. It should be `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` and `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`.

Corrected version:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME == "main" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "develop"
      when: never
```

See [predefined variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).